# How is Multidex support implemented internally?

Tags: android, limit, bytecode, android-multidex

As far as I understand, the 64K limit in the classical dex file arises since the byte code [instruction](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode) for invoke  allows for a 16bit value for indexing the functions within the dex. 
But with the introduction of Multidex support, I am not sure how the function indexing is handled across different dex files on a **byte code level**.

So far I tried to look on the android developer page, other than "a complex process" which happens during startup not much of technical details are mentioned

Answer (score 0):

To support Multidex, your application's main class has to extends the class

> android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

also, you need to add the following dependency in your app module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and set the multiDexEnabled to true

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to know hot multidex solves the problem of referencing a function which is beyond the 16 bit limit. I really want to know how the byte code looks like when you reference functions which are in another dex file.